# Query array column in Postgresql

Tags: node.js, arrays, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an array (items) and I need to query it on postgresql. When I select the hole table the array comes like this:

Array from postgresql

```
[
  [ "product_id: '227534500'", 'quantity: 1' ],
  [ "product_id: '226320600'", 'quantity: 1' ],
  [ "product_id: '208913600'", 'quantity: 1' ],
  [ "product_id: '225421600'", 'quantity: 1' ]
]
```

My array

```
[
  { product_id: '227534500', quantity: 1 },
  { product_id: '226320600', quantity: 1 },
  { product_id: '208913600', quantity: 1 },
  { product_id: '225421600', quantity: 1 }
]
```

What am I doing wrong, as my array on postgresql is this different and how could I query it? (to insert it on postgres, for test, I just copy and paste the 'my array' in the table field

Comment: What is the PostgreSQL data type of that array?

Comment: It is defined as text[]

Comment: That must be a Javascript way of escaping these things.